# collection view background view in ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

     if (recentEmojiArray.count == 0) {

        // Display a message when the table is empty                 

        UILabel *messageLabel1  = [[UILabel alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, clvRecent.bounds.size.width,
        clvRecent.bounds.size.height)];
        messageLabel1.text =@"No recent emojis.";
         [messageLabel1 sizeToFit];
         clvRecent.backgroundView = messageLabel1;

       return 0;                
     }
      else{
            clvRecent.backgroundView = nil;                       
            return recentEmojiArray.count;
      }
    }
```

still background view appearing label with message `"No recent emojis."`I tried to reset the `messageLable1` text to blank. but still appearing in `iOS7` only but in `iOS8` its working fine

Help please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show us how you get the `recentEmojiArray.count` ?

Comment: I am adding recentEmojiArray in the same controller and reloading collection view.

Comment: Is that messageLabel1 text not changing even when you reset to some other string ?

Comment: @Mithun yes I reset messageLabel1.text =@"" but not working...in ios7 only.

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati can you place a break point and check if your array has elements, when you are waiting for them?

Comment: @chandan  I used your same code. But it worked fine for me . Even in ios7 & ios8.. What is clvRecent ?Is that collection View or some other view ?

Comment: @Mithun It is collection view. I have debug the code array has element still appearing in  text in background view "No recent emojis". And data both

Comment: then try to use the collection view instance that you get in the parameter of the collection view datasource method.

Answer (score 0):

just paste your code with this

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

     if (recentEmojiArray.count == 0) {

        // Display a message when the table is empty                 

        UILabel *messageLabel1  = [[UILabel alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, clvRecent.bounds.size.width,
        clvRecent.bounds.size.height)];
        messageLabel1.text =@"No recent emojis.";
         [messageLabel1 sizeToFit];
         clvRecent.backgroundView = messageLabel1;

     }
      else{
            clvRecent.backgroundView = nil;                       
      }
  return recentEmojiArray.count;

}
```

Comment: of course it doesn't he just reverted your implementation, the result is the same